# Django - Wrong Validation Error Message when using self-written Validator

Tags: python, django, validation

I have written my own validator as I have several fields in my form where the same validation is applicable and I wanted to reduce my code with clean_field() methods.
My Form looks like this:

```
class EducationProjectAjaxForm(forms.Form):
    study_fees_year_1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, validators=[validate_study_fees])
    study_fees_year_2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, validators=[validate_study_fees])
    study_fees_year_3 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, validators=[validate_study_fees])
    study_fees_year_4 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, validators=[validate_study_fees])
```

My validator looks like this:

```
def validate_study_fees(data):
    if data:
        if data > 100000:
            raise ValidationError(_('Falscher Wert: %(value)s'),
                                  code='invalid',
                                  params={
                                      'value': 'Es sind maximal 100.000 € Studiengebühren pro Jahr erlaubt.'},
                                  )
        if data % 10 != 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Falscher Wert: %(value)s'),
                                  code='invalid',
                                  params={
                                      'value': 'Der eingetragene Wert muss durch 10 teilbar sein.'},
                                  )
        if data < 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Falscher Wert: %(value)s'),
                                  code='invalid',
                                  params={'value': 'Der Finanzierungsbedarf darf nicht negativ sein'},
                                  )
    return data
```

My problem is that even though the validation itself is correctly applied I get the wrong error message: "Please choose a whole number". The message comes probably from the normal validation for IntegerFields but something like 123 throws the same message even though it is a whole number.
If go the way with clean_study_fees_year_1(self), ... The error message is correctly shown. Is there something to fix my problem so I can have cleaner code?
Thanks in Advance.

Django Version: 1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unique error codes for your different error messages. If you use `code='invalid'`, Django replaces your error message with the default message for the invalid code.

In addition, `value` in the params should be the value you were validating, not an error message.

```
def validate_study_fees(data):
    if data:
        if data > 100000:
            raise ValidationError(_('Es sind maximal 100.000 € Studiengebühren pro Jahr erlaubt.'),
                                  code='too_large',
                                  params={
                                      'value': data},
                                  )
        if data % 10 != 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Der eingetragene Wert muss durch 10 teilbar sein.'),
                                  code='not_divisible_by_10',
                                  params={
                                      'value': data},
                                  )
        if data < 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Der Finanzierungsbedarf darf nicht negativ sein'),
                                  code='negative_value',
                                  params={'value': data},
                                  )
    return data
```

See the [docs on validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators) for more info.